# jQuery: get a reference to a specific element without using id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, jquery-traversing

I'm tinkering a bit with jquery to show a hidden div when a link is clicked. This should be fairly simple, but there's a flaw to it in this case. I have the following markup:

```
<div class="first-row">
        <div class="week">
            <p>Uge 2</p>
            <p>(08-01-11)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="destination">
            <p><a href="#">Les Menuires</a></p>
            <p>(Frankrig)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="days">4</div>
        <div class="transport">Bil</div>
        <div class="lift-card">3 dage</div>
        <div class="accommodation">
            <p><a class="show-info" href="#">Hotel Christelles (halvpension)</a></p>
            <p>4-pers. værelse m. bad/toilet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="order">
            <p><a href="#">2149,-</a></p>
            <p class="old-price">2249,-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hotel-info">
         <!-- The div I want to display on click -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click the "show-info" link I want the "hotel-info" div to display.
My backend devs don't want me to use ids (don't ask me why..) and the above markup is used over and over again to display data. Therefore I need to be able to access the "hotel-info" div in the "first-row" div where the link is clicked.

I've tried to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show-info').click(function() {
        var parentElement = $(this).parent().parent();
        var lastElementOfParent = parentElement.find(".show-hotel");
        lastElementOfParent.show();
    });
});
```

But without a result :-/ Is this possible at all?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The div you're looking to show is called `.hotel-info` yet your code is looking for `.show-hotel` - is that just a typo?

Comment: Rory, thanks - that was a typo, but unfortuneately it didn't solve my problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.show-info').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.accommodation').siblings('.hotel-info').show();
});
```

Even better imo, as it would be independent from *where* the link is in a row, if every "row div" has the same class (I assume only the first one has class `first-row`), you can do:

```
$(this).closest('.row-class').find('.hotel-info').show();
```

**Reference:** [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

---

Explanation why your code does not work:

```
$(this).parent().parent();
```

gives you the `div` with class `.accommodation` and this one has no descendant with class `.hotel-info`.

It is not a good idea to use this kind of traversal for more than one level anyway. If the structure is changed a bit, your code will break. Always try to use methods that won't break on structure changes.

Comment: Hi Felix, that works like a charm! :) the name "first-row" might be quite misleading in that it's actually used every second row to make the background different. So the first solution is briliant ! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're right in not using an ID element to find the DIV you want :)

Use `closest` and `nextAll`

Live demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/xTWzn/

```
$('.show-info').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.accommodation').nextAll('.hotel-info').toggle();
});
```